# Mac OS X: Convert between NSView coordinates and global screen coordinates

Tags: macos, core-graphics, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation

I have the following situation in my multi-monitor setup:

[image: OSX coordinate conversions]

In this example I want to position a window exactly at the coordinates depicted with the yellow arrow. All I do have however, are the coordinates of an NSView that is a subview of the contentView of an NSWindow that spans the entire (bigger,upper) secondary monitor.

Here's how the global coordinate space is defined:

- {0,0}  is the coordinate of the upper left corner of my laptop screen. (green)
- {-296, -1080} is the coordinate of the upper left corner of my second screen (black)
- {0, 800} is the coordinate of the lower left corner (no arrow here)

Thus y is increasing going down from green arrow, decreasing going up from green arrow.

Problem:

How do I convert the point depicted by the yellow arrow ({100,100}, NSView inside NSWindow inside this NSScreen) into that global coordinate system. (**Note**: In an NSView the coordinate system has {0,0} in the bottom left corner, increasing upwards.)

I believe the correct answer is {-196, -980}, but whats the code to get this conversion for any window on any screen?

I have spent too much time on this problem already, so any help is very appreciated.

(Not sure if relevant, but the bottom screen has a retina resolution display.)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Mac OS uses different coordinate systems in various places. Views can define if they have an upwards or downwards pointing y-axis (`isFlipped`). A window's origin is expressed in "screen coordinates" with an upwards y-axis. Screens are arranged using the global coordinate system with y pointing down.

It's better not to try to do the conversion of all the coordinate spaces yourself but let the responsible objects do the job:

```
NSView *yellowView; // your view that contains the point with the yellow arrow.
NSPoint yellowPoint = { 100, 100 };

NSPoint pointInWindow = [yellowView convertPoint:yellowPoint toView:nil];
NSPoint pointOnScreen = [[yellowView window] convertRectToScreen:(CGRect){.origin=pointInWindow}];

NSWindow *newWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:(CGRect){ pointOnScreen, {32, 32}} styleMask: ...];
```

Comment: I think the line:
`NSPoint pointOnScreen = [[yellowView window] convertRectToScreen:(CGRect){.origin=pointInWindow}];`
should be:
`NSPoint pointOnScreen = [[yellowView window] convertRectToScreen:(CGRect){.origin=pointInWindow}].origin;`

Answer (score 8):

The Swift (4.0) version of the accepted answer is basically the same:

```
let yellowView: NSView // your view that contains the point with the yellow arrow.
let yellowPoint = NSPoint(x: 100, y: 100)

let pointInWindow = yellowView.convert(yellowPoint, to: nil)
let pointOnScreen = yellowView.window?.convertToScreen(NSRect(origin: pointInWindow, size: .zero)).origin ?? .zero

let contentRect = NSRect(origin: pointOnScreen, size: NSSize(width: 32, height: 32))
let newWindow = NSWindow(contentRect: contentRect, styleMask: ...)
```

The following is an alternate way to do it:

```
let someView: NSView // Some existing view
var rect: NSRect

rect = NSRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 0, height: 0)
rect = someView.convert(rect, to: nil)
rect = someView.window?.convertToScreen(rect) ?? rect
rect.size = NSSize(width: 32, height: 32)
let newWindow = NSWindow(contentRect: rect, styleMask: ...)
```

The latter way simply sets the rect up ahead of time. Here's a play-by-play for those who like walkthroughs:

**1. Create a rectangle.** Initialize a zero-sized rectangle at the desired location within the view's coordinate system.

```
let someView: NSView // Some existing view
var rect = NSRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 0, height: 0)
```

**2. Convert from view to window.** Convert the rectangle from the view's coordinate system to the window's coordinate system by specifying `nil` for the destination `view`.

```
rect = someView.convert(rect, to: nil)
```

**3. Convert from window to screen.** Next, convert the rectangle from the window's coordinate system to the screen's coordinate system.

*Note that `someView.window` may be `nil`, so we use optional chaining (i.e. the `?` in `window?`) and fallback to the original value of `rect` if that's the case.* This probably isn't necessary, but it's a good habit to get into.

```
rect = someView.window?.convertToScreen(rect) ?? rect
```

**4. Set the rectangle's size.** Update the rectangle with the desired size of the new window.

```
rect.size = NSSize(width: 32, height: 32)
```

**5. Create the window.** Initialize a new window with the converted rectangle.

```
let newWindow = NSWindow(contentRect: rect, styleMask: ...)
```